# How to calculate cells with Numbers?

Tags: excel, numbers, spreadsheet, calculation

I intend to do simple calculations in Numbers but always getting an exception.
[image]

I will enter values in the B to H and select a time unit in the last column cell.
What I want to effort is, that whenever I select another item in the dropdownlist I want to adapt the entered values. So, when I entered values in "ns" and then select "ms" I want to update the entered values by dividing the value by 1000...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One solution would be to create a separate output table where you do the calculation accordingly.
If you want to directly change the (input) cells, you want to have a look into iOS Shortcuts, AppleScript or JavaScript for Automation (JXA).

Comment: I already suspected that I can't achieve it with a simplemuse of functions but had to implement some specific code (scripts, macros, ...).

Comment: whats your app? Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: Numbers on a MacBook Pro.